# Merging several feature classes into one pre-existing feature class in geodatabase with coded domains?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, merge, domains

I have several point feature classes that I want to merge into one pre-made feature class with coded domains. The pre-made feature class already has all of the fields named (although differently from the multiple feature classes, so I will need to be able to match them with where they go) and has all of the coded values set.

Outside of manual manipulation (merging, field calc all values to coded values, etc) is there an easier and simpler way to accomplish this?

So far I haven't been able to find anything about joining/merging non-domain GDB feature classes with coded-domain GDB feature classes.

Comment: Technically, all of those manipulations do not have to be manual. Once you have figured out your workflow, nothing prevents you to automate it using Model Builder or a script. That only half of the answer to your problem though.

Comment: Build dictionaries and use cursors/field calculate to convert your values to domain codes. Look at http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/domain-to-table.htm. Then use field mapping to match your fields. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/python/mapping-fields.htm

Comment: @BenSNadler Ended up using this. Calc'd the fields to match the coded values and then used the Append tool to add the original feature classes to the combined one. Thanks!

Comment: @BenSNadler It sounds like you may have enough in your comment to make a brief answer that the asker would accept.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @BenSNadler:

> Build dictionaries and use cursors/field calculate to convert your
>   values to domain codes. Look at
>   http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/domain-to-table.htm.
>   Then use field mapping to match your fields.
>   http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/python/mapping-fields.htm